# 3des encryption in iPhone padding issue

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption, 3des

I have a problem using 3DES encryption in my iPhone app. I have 9 byte message to be encrypted. When I use `kCCOptionECBMode`, the first 8 byte block is encrypted correctly (I have a sample result produced by server). How can I encrypt the last byte? When I use `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding` or `kCCOptionECBMode| kCCOptionPKCS7Padding`, it gives wrong result with status `kCCBufferTooSmall`. I have gone through some posts related to 3DES encryption on SO but not helped me.

```
 ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithm3DES,
                       kCCOptionECBMode,
                       vkey, 
                       kCCKeySize3DES,
                       vinitVec,
                       vplainText,
                       plainTextBufferSize,
                       (void *)bufferPtr,
                       [data length],
                       &movedBytes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with data length parameter. I should calculate data length after padding and pass it to function.